# Dynamic section height based on viewport

Tags: jquery, dynamic, height

I've developed a vertical theme with full screen background with anchor smoothscrolling navigation. 
I'm trying to adapt background section on the viewport height because on high resolution some user can see the next and previous section even if they're navigating on a specific anchor.

For example: a user is navigating www.mysite.com/#aboutus but on high resolutions you can see previous (#home) and next (#portfolio) section content and background.

So I've got three problems:

1. All backgrounds have to adapt viewport considering that there are one header and a footer of fixed position and height
2. The section must adapt to the viewport height on resize and on load
3. The body must scrollTo specific anchor adapting to the viewport initial size or resize

For the first problem I'm using this script to set height dynamically

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){ // On load
        $(window).load(function(){ // On load
            $('#section_name').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
            $('#section_name').css({'margin-bottom':'200px'});


        });
```

I tried to add dynamically the margin-bottom to push down next section content. 
The aim is to adapt background and section content to viewport height in order to avoid seeing previous and next section in high resolutions.

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieve with help of media query in css.You can write separate css for each device.
For example :-

```
@media screen and ( max-height: 600px ){
    body {
           height:600px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pramod. Well I think it would be too tricky do this only with CSS... I would consider too many cases to adapt the sections. Anyone can help me with jquery ?